# Book recommendations on physics of music and musical instruments

Tags: resource-recommendations, acoustics, frequency, applied-physics

I am pursuing a degree in Mathematics and have a strong interest on music. I would like to understand the physical basis of how is music made. Does someone know some bibliography on this subject?

Comment: There are some (excessively?) high-level mathematics books on music too: Mazzola wrote a few.